# AndroidManifest.xml "Las estructuras del documento XML deben empezar y finalizar en la misma entidad."

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola cómo están? espero que bien.
Tengo un problema con el archivo AndroidManifest.xml lo he modificado y ahora se desconfiguró y tiene el siguiente error "Las estructuras del documento XML deben empezar y finalizar en la misma entidad."

El error apareció luego de que cambié unas líneas de código para agregar un TextView al ToolBar de mi aplicación

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.flixarts.ar.englishnow">
        <!-- Required to act as a custom watch face. -->
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> <!-- Required for complications to receive complication data and open the provider chooser. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.wearable.permission.RECEIVE_COMPLICATION_DATA" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
               ``:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
     >

    <activity android:name=".future">.     </activity>
    <activity android:name=".quiz" />
    <activity android:name=".shopping" />
    <activity android:name=".holidays" />
    <activity android:name=".adjectives" />
    <activity android:name=".adverbs" />
    <activity android:name=".nouns" />
    <activity android:name=".verbtobe" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers12" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers11" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers10" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers9" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers8" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers7" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers6" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers5" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers4" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers3" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers2" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers1" />
    <activity android:name=".thereis" />
    <activity android:name=".school" />
    <activity android:name=".despedidas" />
    <activity android:name=".food" />
    <activity android:name=".family" />
    <activity android:name=".colors" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers" />
    <activity android:name=".congratulations" />
<activity android:name=".presentaciones" />
<activity android:name=".saludos" />
<activity android:name=".works" />
<activity android:name=".presentcontinuous" />
<activity android:name=".tohave" />
<activity android:name=".verbs" />
<activity android:name=".menuscreen" />
<activity android:name=".Pantalla2" />
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.actions"
        android:resource="@xml/buttons"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Actualmente no estoy pudiendo correr la aplicación, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme gracias!
De hecho todavía no me he familiarizado con el archivo AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

El AndroidManifest.xml es incorrecto, estas cerrando `<application>` y estas agregando otro inicio de `<manifest>`, todos los tag deben tener cierre, pero en el caso de manifest y application solo debes tener un elemento.

Este sería tu archivo manifiesto corregido :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.flixarts.ar.englishnow">
    <!-- Required to act as a custom watch face. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> <!-- Required for complications to receive complication data and open the provider chooser. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.wearable.permission.RECEIVE_COMPLICATION_DATA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    >

    <activity android:name=".future" />
    <activity android:name=".quiz" />
    <activity android:name=".shopping" />
    <activity android:name=".holidays" />
    <activity android:name=".adjectives" />
    <activity android:name=".adverbs" />
    <activity android:name=".nouns" />
    <activity android:name=".verbtobe" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers12" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers11" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers10" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers9" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers8" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers7" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers6" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers5" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers4" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers3" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers2" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers1" />
    <activity android:name=".thereis" />
    <activity android:name=".school" />
    <activity android:name=".despedidas" />
    <activity android:name=".food" />
    <activity android:name=".family" />
    <activity android:name=".colors" />
    <activity android:name=".numbers" />
    <activity android:name=".congratulations" />
    <activity android:name=".presentaciones" />
    <activity android:name=".saludos" />
    <activity android:name=".works" />
    <activity android:name=".presentcontinuous" />
    <activity android:name=".tohave" />
    <activity android:name=".verbs" />
    <activity android:name=".menuscreen" />
    <activity android:name=".Pantalla2" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.actions"
        android:resource="@xml/buttons"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Es muy importante que revises la documentación:

[Manifest de la aplicación Android.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro?hl=es-419)